# How to store an output of a function as individual entries rather than a list?

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a function that gives an output of 100+ elements for each input, and each output is appended to a list creating a list of lists:

```
def func(mols: List[str]):
    feaut = []
    for i, mol in enumerate(mols):
        feaut.append(FG.features_generator(mol)) #This is calling another function from a 
     return feaut                                # package I am using
```

This is the output:

```
  [[2.1874960973678963,10.264662506490405,2.7071067811865475,1.9855985596534889,...],
   [2.475534205527556,24.264662506490403,2.7071067811865475,1.9472135954999579,...]]
```

What is required is to create a DataFrame that has the element passed into the function in one column and each element of the output in separate columns, like the following:

| element passed | output1 | output2 | output3 | outputN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| one | 2.187 | 10.264 | 2.707 | 1.985 |
| two | 2.475 | 24.26 | 2.70 | 1.94 |

What I currently have is:

| element passed | output |
| --- | --- |
| one | [2.187,10.264,2.707,1.985...] |
| two | [2.475,24.26,2.70,1.94... ] |

Comment: Instead of a list make feaut a dictionary using i for the keys and whatever is returned by FG.features_generator for the values.

Comment: @norie The problem is that the values are stored as a list of size 100, what I need is to divide up that list into separate columns.

Comment: If you created a dictionary as I suggested you could then use pandas `DataFrame.from_dict` with the orient argument set to `index` to get the data in the  format you want. I'd post the code but the question has been closed.

Comment: create a `index = []` then `index.append(mol)` then just use `pd.DataFrame(feaut, index=index)`